# Adding improper tail to given Erlang list

Tags: list, erlang

How do I add an improper tail (e.g. |<<>>) to a proper Erlang list "Parent" with an arbitrary number of elements? I need this to create a range scan upper limit value for matchspecs on a MNESIA table where list keys represent object hierarchy.
To my understanding (inspired by the sext project) any children of a parent key `Parent=[T1,T2,T3]` (T1,T2,T2 are arbitrary Erlang Terms) can be found with matchspecs asking for:

```
Child > [T1,T2,T3] and Child < [T1,T2,T3|<<>>]
```

Given only Parent as a whole, how do I calculate the upper value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the improper list you're looking for, just append the empty binary `<<>>` to the list:

```
Parent ++ <<>>.
```

For example, if `Parent` is `[t1,t2,t3]`:

```
1> Parent = [t1,t2,t3].
[t1,t2,t3]
2> Parent ++ <<>>.
[t1,t2,t3|<<>>]
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, this simple solution was too easy to overlook.